# No output from loop calling r cor.test()

Tags: r, loops

I am trying to use the `cor.test()` r function in a loop and I cannot quite get it to 'function'. I can call the items individually, but I would prefer to use a loop.

A selection of my code looks like this:

```
hNames= scan(fileName, nlines = 1, what = character(), sep = ',')
mydata = read.table(fileName, header = TRUE, sep = ',')
names = c(hNames[2:length(hNames)])

for (i in names(mydata[2:length(mydata)]))
{
        for (j in names(mydata[2:length(mydata)]))
        {cor.test(mydata[[i]], mydata[[j]], method='spearman')}
}
```

Which does not work (there is no output), however, this does:

```
cor.test(mydata$Bacteroidetes, mydata$Actinobacteria, method = 'spearman')
```

I have tried several variations on the loop, but I have consistently gotten an error that says 'x' (or 'y') must be a numeric vector.

My data looks like this (print(mydata))

```
PHYLUM Actino Bacter ...Tenericutes
x1     25       45    ...8
x1     26       42    ...8
x2     40       43    ...7
x2     42       41    ...5
x2     40       41    ...5
```

Or in its original format:

```
PHYLUM,Actinobacteria,Bacteroidetes,...Tenericutes
x1,25,45,...8
x1,26,42,...8
x2,40,43,...7
x2,42,41,...5
x2,40,41,...5
```

What am I doing incorrectly and how can I change it s.t. the code produces some output?

Thank you kindly.

Comment: You can use `combn` and avoid R `for loop`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Surround your call to cor.test with print.

Comment: @user2642180 To expand slightly, when you call `cor.test` directly from the interactive command line, it will return an "htest" object. When that happens at the command line, R will automatically call that objects print method. However, in scripts, inside functions or loops, this won't happen, so you have to do it explicitly.

Comment: @joran Thanks for providing more details for them.  I was on my phone and *loathe* typing on that thing so I kept it quite brief.